# Single Node Deletion in Cheng and Church Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, algorithms

Cheng and Church Algorithm is a biclustering algorithm or an unsupervised learning task with which both rows and columns in a data matrix can be placed in concurrent clusters.

In the [original paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/12345321_Biclustering_of_Expression_Data), authors explained that a row or column of an input matrix $A$ with the largest $d(i)$ or $d(j)$ should be removed in single node deletion phase:

- Find the row $i \in I$ with largest: $d(i) = \frac{\sum_{j \in J} (a_{ij} - a_{iJ} - a_{Ij} + a_{IJ})}{\lvert J \rvert}$
- Find the column $j \in J$ with largest: $d(j) = \frac{\sum{i \in I} (a_{ij} - a_{iJ} - a_{Ij} + a_{IJ})}{\lvert I \rvert}$

I found one implementation of the algorithm trying to do the following operations for single node deletion:

```py
row_max_msr = np.argmax(row_msr) #finding the index of rows having largest d(i)
col_max_msr = np.argmax(col_msr) #finding the index of columns having largest d(j)

#Continue with removing row where $d(i) >= d(j)$ or column $d(j) > d(i)$ 
if row_msr[row_max_msr] >= col_msr[col_max_msr]: 
    row2remove = row_indices[row_max_msr]
    rows[row2remove] = False
else:
    col2remove = col_indices[col_max_msr]
    cols[col2remove] = False
```

I was wondering whether anyone has a suggestion for this matter. I don't mean that the code has installation or execution problem. Actually, I want to be sure of the logic to be aligned with the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> Padilha, V. A. & Campello, R. J. G. B. (2017). A systematic comparative evaluation of biclustering techniques. BMC Bioinformatics, 18(1):55.

https://github.com/padilha/biclustlib

It needs the r-bicluster library which is available on conda https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-biclust

Citing the authors GitHub page for instructions

```py
import numpy as np

from biclustlib.algorithms import ChengChurchAlgorithm
from biclustlib.datasets import load_yeast_tavazoie

# load yeast data used in the original Cheng and Church's paper
data = load_yeast_tavazoie().values

# missing value imputation suggested by Cheng and Church
missing = np.where(data < 0.0)
data[missing] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=800, size=len(missing[0]))

# creating an instance of the ChengChurchAlgorithm class and running with the parameters of the original study
cca = ChengChurchAlgorithm(num_biclusters=100, msr_threshold=300.0, multiple_node_deletion_threshold=1.2)
biclustering = cca.run(data)
print(biclustering)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, I don't mean that the code has installation or execution problem. Actually, I want to be sure of the logic to be aligned with the algorithm.